# Using an array or the map function to improving on a nested loop performance to change/substitute cell colours in googlescript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array.prototype.map

Hi still a relative newbie here...I've got some nested loops which cycle through each cell in a sheet range looking for a background color and if it finds a match then the background colour is changed. Yes - I am sorry for this approach(!). Am thinking I must be able to get the background colours via an array and then apply a transformation to the array using .map(?) but have experimented and haven't worked it out so far. Other examples on S/O don't show a substitute approach that I have been able to apply across. Any advice/thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
function myColorFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("My Sheet");
 
 for (var y = 1; y < 70; y++){
   for (var x = 1; x < 50; x++){
   var bghex = ss.getRange(y,x).getBackground();
   if(bghex == '#001d66') { //occasional cell colour
     ss.getRange(y,x).setBackground("#027db6");
   }
   else if (bghex == '#00288b') { //main bkgrnd colour
     ss.getRange(y,x).setBackground("#0297db");
   }
   else if (bghex == '#fbf025') { //yellow fill-in
     ss.getRange(y,x).setBackground("#fdd201");
   }
   }
   Logger.log('Line ' + y + ' complete');
 }
}
```

Comment: Alfredo's advise of using `getBackgrounds()` is the way to go. Moreover, why do you think `.map()` is fast? (I'd even go as far as saying vectorized functions are often slower than loops in mainly OOP languages.)

Comment: Why> a mix of naivety and hope :-D will test both for time and test the hypothesis. Thanks for the point, v helpful for my thinking

Comment: Share it when you are done :) I wonder if anyone has asked for a reliable way to test computational efficiency/time in Apps Script

Comment: So like for like - same sheet color test...looping y,x vs Diego's answer is 3 mins 33 secs for the loop y,x versus 2 seconds for Diego's solution. Massive performance difference. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be like this, using a nested `.map()` function and using `getBackgrounds()` first to populate the 2D Array of cell colors, then replacing it using an if-else statement, from there you can use `setBackgrounds()` to apply the changes to the whole range.

```
function myColorFunction2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("My Sheet");
  var range = ss.getRange(1,1,70,50);
  var bghex = range.getBackgrounds();

  bghex.map(row => row.map((elem,index) => {
     if(elem == '#001d66'){
       row[index] = '#027db6';
     }
     else if (elem == '#00288b') {
        row[index] = '#0297db';
     }
     else if (elem == '#fbf025') {
       row[index] = '#fdd201';
     }
  }));

  range.setBackgrounds(bghex);
  Logger.log(bghex);
}
```

**Output:**

This amount took about only 1 second runtime duration:

[image]

Ref:

- [setBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackgrounds(String))
- [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getBackgrounds())
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `getBackground()`, use `getBackgrounds()`, this way instead of getting individual values, you get an array where you can apply the `map()` function.

Here is an example replacing red backgrounds.

```
function myColorFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("My Sheet");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B10");
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds(); // Return 2D arr

  // Applies map() function on each row
  for (let i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++) {
    backgrounds[i] = backgrounds[i].map(function(item) { return item == "#ff0000" ? "#0000ff" : item; });
  }

  // Set new backgrounds
  range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alfredo, brilliant - this was the bit I couldn't get to: { return item == "#ff0000" ? "#0000ff" : item; }. For multiple color switches - what makes more sense please...building out several conditions in that term (if possible) or 3 separate loops (for 3 colours)?

Comment: Call the map() function 3 times inside the same loop.